# $\int_{E_n}f d \mu \rightarrow 0$ implies $\mu(E_n) \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive measurable function and $E_n$ be a sequence of measurable sets, prove that if 
$\int_{E_n}f d \mu \rightarrow 0$ implies $\mu(E_n) \rightarrow  0$. I have try to decompose $[0,1]$ into $\{f\geq 1/n\}$ but I have no idea after that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269295/showing-lim-n-to-infty-me-n-0-assuming-f-0-a-e-and-lim-n-to?rq=1

Comment: Thank you so much and i have tried to serach but no results